# Jenkins can't find RestKit for my iOS app but it works interactively

Tags: ios, jenkins, restkit

I am using Jenkins for continuous compliance and my iOS project is failing to run. My app builds and runs just fine interactively. RestKit is a git submodule in my project.

The job fails with this:

```
CompileC build/testApp.build/Release-iphoneos/testApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/main.o testApp/main.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd /Users/bob/.jenkins/jobs/appNameOut-iOS/workspace/testApp
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DCONFIGURATION_Release -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -iquote /Users/bob/.jenkins/jobs/appNameOut-iOS/workspace/testApp/build/testApp.build/Release-iphoneos/testApp.build/testApp-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/bob/.jenkins/jobs/appNameOut-iOS/workspace/testApp/build/testApp.build/Release-iphoneos/testApp.build/testApp-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/bob/.jenkins/jobs/appNameOut-iOS/workspace/testApp/build/testApp.build/Release-iphoneos/testApp.build/testApp-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/bob/.jenkins/jobs/appNameOut-iOS/workspace/testApp/build/testApp.build/Release-iphoneos/testApp.build/testApp-project-headers.hmap -iquote../GMGridView/GMGridView -iquote/Users/bob/.jenkins/jobs/appNameOut-iOS/workspace/testApp/build/Release-iphoneos/../../Headers "-iquote‚Äù/Users/bob/.jenkins/jobs/appNameOut-iOS/workspace/testApp/build/Release-iphoneos/usr/local/lib/include‚Äù" "-iquote‚Äù/Users/bob/.jenkins/jobs/appNameOut-iOS/workspace/testApp/build/UninstalledProducts/include‚Äù" -I/Users/bob/.jenkins/jobs/appNameOut-iOS/workspace/testApp/build/Release-iphoneos/include -I../GMGridView/GMGridView -I/Users/bob/.jenkins/jobs/appNameOut-iOS/workspace/testApp/build/Release-iphoneos/../../Headers -I/Users/bob/.jenkins/jobs/appNameOut-iOS/workspace/testApp/build/testApp.build/../UninstalledProducts/include "-I‚Äù/Users/bob/.jenkins/jobs/appNameOut-iOS/workspace/testApp/build/UninstalledProducts/include‚Äù" "-I‚Äù/Users/bob/.jenkins/jobs/appNameOut-iOS/workspace/testApp/build/Release-iphoneos/usr/local/lib/include‚Äù" -I/Users/bob/.jenkins/jobs/appNameOut-iOS/workspace/testApp/build/testApp.build/Release-iphoneos/testApp.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/Users/bob/.jenkins/jobs/appNameOut-iOS/workspace/testApp/build/testApp.build/Release-iphoneos/testApp.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/bob/.jenkins/jobs/appNameOut-iOS/workspace/testApp/build/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/bob/.jenkins/jobs/appNameOut-iOS/workspace/testApp/QuincyKit -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -include /var/folders/zn/81z3gcmj00xg6rn2mg7qzgvh0000gn/C/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/testApp-Prefix-glmuagpwjeknolcbkgvqhsdakvok/testApp-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/bob/.jenkins/jobs/appNameOut-iOS/workspace/testApp/build/testApp.build/Release-iphoneos/testApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/main.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/bob/.jenkins/jobs/appNameOut-iOS/workspace/testApp/build/testApp.build/Release-iphoneos/testApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/main.dia -c /Users/bob/.jenkins/jobs/appNameOut-iOS/workspace/testApp/testApp/main.m -o /Users/bob/.jenkins/jobs/appNameOut-iOS/workspace/testApp/build/testApp.build/Release-iphoneos/testApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/main.o
In file included from /Users/bob/.jenkins/jobs/appNameOut-iOS/workspace/testApp/testApp/main.m:11:
/Users/bob/.jenkins/jobs/appNameOut-iOS/workspace/testApp/testApp/AppDelegate.h:14:9: fatal error: 'RestKit/RestKit.h' file not found
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
    ^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the RestKit submodule was properly being pulled, and that RestKit was being built properly, but that the header include paths were not finding the RestKit files when building via the command line while it did work via the GUI.  I edited the pbxproj file, adding the required header search paths whenever I found an input for such things.

Comment: Did you determine what the precise difference was between command line and GUI invocations? I have the same circumstance, despite having the 'recursive' flag on the relevant framework search path.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new build step, for a shell-command, before the xcode build step. stick this in it:

git submodule update --init --recursive

The idea is this: Assuming "*runs just fine interactively*" meant "It builds fine when I build it with Xcode on my machine, which has the project's git repository locally cloned"; it seems that your local git clone has the restkit git sub module checked out OK. Your Jenkins job doesn't. It is never updating the submodules after it git pull's. It needs to, in order to build the job in Jenkins.

Comment: I added this build step but there was no change. I can see that even without this step, RestKit is present. I am still failing with the same error. I can see that RestKit exists in the top level of my git repo, at the same level as my Xcode project, and there is no symbolic link or copy of RestKit inside of my Xcode directory - could that be causing the failure?

Comment: There should be no reason for a symbolic link. The Git submodule for Restkit will be cloned at the same place in the directory structure, regardless of whether it's Jenkin's that's pulling the repo or you on your local machine. When you are building with Jenkins are you building with the same workspace/scheme/target? If you are using different targets are they *each* configured correctly (ie header paths, -ObjC linking, etc)?